# Array of Bitmaps Displayed in a GridView using ArrayAdapter. Android

Tags: java, android, gridview, bitmap, android-arrayadapter

I'm currently trying to populate a GridView with an array of Bitmaps. When trying to use this code:

```
public void onResultReceived_Image(Bitmap[] bitmaps)
{

    ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Bitmap>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bitmaps);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

I get toString exceptions, which makes sense considering that `simple_list_item_1` is attempting to use a text view to populate the grid (as is my understanding anyway).

I've put some research into custom array adapters but so far haven't found any particularly useful or relevant bits of material towards specifically Bitmaps and gridViews. Is there an easy fix or simple implementation of custom array adapters that anyone can point me to? New to android and Java.

Comment: Bitmaps can be displayed using ImageView. So, you need a custom adapter with a data list of Bitmaps and a ViewHolder containing an ImageView. IMO every example with a ListView will do for getting a basic understanding, there isn't that much difference to a GridView from the adapter point of view.